# Sequelize transaction блокирует поток NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, sequelize.js

Я использую следующую конфигурацию Sequelize

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, pass, {
    host,
    dialect,
    dialectOptions: {
        decimalNumbers: true,
    },
    operatorsAliases: {
        $and: Op.and,
        $or: Op.or,
        $gte: Op.gte,
        $lte: Op.lte,
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
    },
    timezone: '+03:00',
    // logging: true,
});
```

Мое приложение в основном состоит из transaction

```
router.post('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
 const transactionQuery = await sequeilze.transaction();
 ...
});
```

При частом обращений sequelize блокирует поток node, и выкидывает ошибку operation timeout.

Есть ли решение моей проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы наткнулись на такую же проблему, то скорее всего вы забыли где-то выполнить завершение транзакций через transaction.commit() или внутри транзакции вы выполняете запрос в бд на добавление/изменение записи, но не передали транзакцию, поэтому транзакция не может завершиться (Скорее всего у вас эта проблема). Это и блокирует весь поток NodeJS.